# Datatable select filter

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

I'm trying to create custom filters for my datatable using `<select>`.

How can I make for when someone selects one of the options, the datatable display the items according to the selection without having to refresh the page?

DATATABLE CODE:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthMenu": [
          [10, 25, 50, -1],
          [10, 25, 50, "Todas"]
        ],
        responsive: true,
        language: {
          search: "_INPUT_",
          searchPlaceholder: "Filtro", //Ignorem isso
        }


      });

      var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

    });
```

how can I also do so that several options of the same value are not created?

Code:

```
<select class="form-control" placeholder="pais" name="pais">
<option selected >PAÍS</option>
<?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>
<option value="<?=$row['pais']?>"> <?php echo $row['pais']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<select class="form-control" placeholder="pais" name="pais">
<option selected >PAÍS</option>
<option value="BRAZIL"> BRAZIL</option>
<option value="BRAZIL"> BRAZIL</option>
<option value="BRAZIL"> BRAZIL</option>
<option value="BRAZIL"> BRAZIL</option>
<option value="BRAZIL"> BRAZIL</option>
</select>
```

I select "BRAZIL", the datatable list all items with the country "BRAZIL".

More codes:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
require_once("ct.php");
session_start();

$resultado = array(); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM infh";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
$resultado = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);




<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th style="display:none;">ID</th>
                        <th>BIN</th>                         
                        <th>BANDEIRA</th>
                        <th>LEVEL</th>
                        <th>BANCO</th>                                             
                        <th>PAÍS</th>

                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                     <tr>
                        <th style="display:none;">ID</th>
                        <th>BIN</th>
                        <th>BANDEIRA</th>
                        <th>LEVEL</th>
                        <th>BANCO</th>
                        <th>PAÍS</th>

                     </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="display:none;" class="id_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                        <td class="seis_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo substr($row['pr'],0,6); ?></td>
                        <td class="bandeira_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['bandeira']; ?></td>
                        <td class="level_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['level']; ?></td>
                        <td class="banco_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['banco']; ?></td>
                        <td class="pais_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['pais']; ?></td>

                     </tr>
                     <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
```

Comment: Where does `$resultado` come from? If it's from a database query you might as well add a `distinct` to your query. Either way, you should tell/show us how you obtain it by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53283413/edit) your question.

Comment: Ready. I edited

Comment: Developer advice: always a bad idea to mix all the stack together. You're rendering HTML from PHP which makes the code very hard to maintain and debug. Pass the data from PHP to JavaScript and render on the client-side. Even better: make an API to serve data.

Comment: This is the problem, I have no idea how to do this